# Django: Dynamically set SITE_ID in settings.py based on URL?

Tags: python, django, web

What is a good way to dynamically set SITE_ID in settings.py based on domain name in URL?

I have an app that will be running with too many domain names (city based) that a custom settings.py file for each domain is just not doable.

Is there a way to set it dynamically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do a custom middleware which reads the request and sets the SITE_ID. I use this code on one of my sites:

```
class SiteMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.DEFAULT_SITE_ID)

        request.current_site = current_site
        settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id
```

You should look at Django's documentation on middleware to find out how to add your own middleware. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and your time! What do you import in the custom `middleware.py` in order to make it work? I got some errors. Assuming some imports are needed. Also, how do you have the `SITE_ID` setup in the `settings.py` as it seems to be overwriting with whatever value is set in the `settings.py file`. Thanks again!

Comment: I have been working on this and I have question: Are you suggesting that this middleware replace the existing sites middleware?

Comment: @AdamS This would not replace the sites middleware, but uses it for the purpose of dynamically setting the SITE_ID that the sites middleware looks for by default

Comment: This is solid, I would rename it `DynamicSiteMiddleware` to avoid some of the confusion of the people in the comments, but I'm using this and it's working quite well! Avoids the super annoying WARNING messages from the subdomains.middleware we were getting on localhost.
```
        subdomains.middleware WARNING  The host localhost:8000 does not belong to the domain <domain from Site>,
        unable to identify the subdomain for this request
```

Answer (score 7):

The middleware code form seems to have changed. The current (Django v3.1) form of the code (that seems to work):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class DynamicSiteDomainMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.DEFAULT_SITE_ID)

        request.current_site = current_site
        settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id


        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I may need to update one older project that is still the SITE_ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for Django v3.2.

This code is not very different compared to earlier answers, so I won't explain how this works.
However, I believe that writing custom middleware changed slightly in v3.2. The key difference is subclassing MiddleWareMixin. I put this code in middleware.py, and add it to the MIDDLEWARE list in settings.py.
The second change compared to above answers is the use of SITE_ID directly from settings.py instead of DEFAULT_SITE_ID, since I see no point in having both these set in settings.py.

```
# middleware.py
class DynamicSiteMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Make all domain names available through request.site
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
        request.site = current_site
        settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
   'library.middleware.DynamicSiteMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the explanation there, not in the comments.