# django SITE_ID by query

Tags: django

I have a django app.  I'm adding a second site.

So now I need to set SITE_ID correctly.  This is easy enough, except that since it is the primary key id in the Site table, this means the value is dependent on the order in which sites have been added (and, eventually, deleted).  That's fragile, without even discussing how developers will sort this if they've done any scratch work in that table.  Much better to set it by query.

```
SITE_ID = Site.objects.get(name='my_site_name').id
```

But the `settings_myapp.py` file, which sets `WSGI_APPLICATION`, is pretty much the only one that might know which app I'm running.  I could try modifying `settings` in that site-specific settings file, but importing settings at that point leads to an error that `SECRET_KEY` is not yet defined.

Is there a robust way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Dynamically set SITE\_ID in settings.py based on URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659877/django-dynamically-set-site-id-in-settings-py-based-on-url)

Comment: Thanks!  That's a clever solution to much of the problem, but it leaves developers high and dry (hostname is localhost, but devs might want to develop/test other site paths).  Perhaps setting DEFAULT_SITE_ID is the right way to approach that.

Comment: Or.....you don't set SITE_ID, because CurrentSiteMiddleware already selects based on hostname if SITE_ID is unset. Then your only task is to not forward unsupported hostnames.

Comment: @Melvyn How does that work for develers, where hostname will be something like "localhost"?

Comment: You change the hostname on the development environment. When you import an (obfuscated) database, you post process all site models and append ".localhost" to the hostname, then developers can access that site using "example.com.localhost" as if it was the production instance.

Comment: I'm left with a sticking point: urlpatterns.  I've two sites that recognise slightly different URL sets, but the very clever middleware solution doesn't provide me with hostname data until a request happens.
(I've summarised all of this above.)

Comment: I've now completed my answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a summary of how I solved the problem I stated in my question.  Unbeknownst to me when I asked the question, there are actually several facets demanding different approaches.

A bit of middleware helps enormously for deployed instances (i.e., not dev).  [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037438/833300) provides a django 3.1 ready code snippet, as a solution that existed in times past is no longer compatible with modern django.

For developers, I added this to my `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_SITE_ID = os.getenv('DEFAULT_SITE_ID')
```

And so the snippet above becomes this:

```
class DynamicSiteDomainMiddleware:
    default_site_id = None

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.
        self.default_site_id = settings.DEFAULT_SITE_ID
        if self.default_site_id is not None:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=self.default_site_id)

    def __call__(self, request):
        if self.default_site_id is None:
            try:
                current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
            except Site.DoesNotExist:
                current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.DEFAULT_SITE_ID)
        else:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=self.default_site_id)

        request.current_site = current_site
        settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

In other words, if a developer has set `DEFAULT_SITE_ID` (e.g., on the commandline when invoking `manage.py`) that value is used.  Otherwise, we look at SNI on requests.

This leaves one bit of the puzzle unanswered: what to do about `urlpatterns`?  I've two sites (soon three) that have slightly different URL schemes.  But in the main `urls.py`, the site information is not yet available under this clever middleware solution, as urlpatterns is (naturally and necessarily) set before any requests happen.

The approach that smells best to me sets an environment variables so that `settings.py` can set `ROOT_URLCONF` for its specific case.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = os.getenv('ROOT_URLCONF', 'transport_nantes.urls_tn')
```

An apparent disadvantage is that we end up stuck with two incompatible mechanisms for setting the site data: `DEFAULT_SITE_ID` + SNI and also `ROOT_URLCONF`.  This isn't as bad as it seems, however, since these are two independent aspects of the problem: what site I am and what URL scheme I mean to have.  This required a very small change to production and staging deployment code to set the appropriate environment variable.

Finally, in each of the `url_XYZ.py` files, I set a variable for the base template for that version of the site.  (At issue is that the links are different.  If it were just changing the logo, it would be easier.)  I pass that value in a dict to the included url files, and so I can use that knowledge when rendering views, even though view functions are often shared amongst several sites and URL schemes.

So why not set an environment variable for the `SITE_ID` as well?  This goes back to the initial question: the site id is fragile, being the primary key in the sites table.  It is reasonable to imagine some bit of maintenance that leaves the sites table unchanged except for a changed primary key (for example, an inadvertent deletion followed by recreation of the record).  So looking up values by name is more robust.

On the other hand, the `ROOT_URLCONF` variable has the advantage that it's *not* tied to the sites table.  For example, site X has a certain URL scheme, which is true whether X is running in production or staging or testing, all of which have different FQDN's.